# Run app with a clean database everytime

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm creating an app which uses a database.

I'm refining the database, fixing errors and so on. But the `onCreate()` method of my helper is called only once. So, after the first test, the app's still using the old, and wrong database.

I can implement the `onUpgrade()` method, but this seems odd to me, since I'm actually fixing errors and I'll find many of them. Is this the right way to do it? Playing with database version numbers?

Is there any simpler method?

Comment: in `onCreate()`, can't you just implement a method that will remove the DB every time (and then create it again from scratch).  That way, whenever the app is run, it wipes out all of the current data before doing anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your app starts, you can physically delete the database:

```
File myDB = getDatabasePath("my_database.db");
myDB.delete();
```

The next call you make to your database ContentProvider will then create the database from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

If your are testing/creating your app, then just delete your database in onCreate() method on your Activity:

```
this.deleteDatabase("your_database_name");
```

But for the future release of your published app, i suggest to learn and implement the method **onUpgrade()**.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that method, so +1 for an answer that I believe is as good as mine.